# eval fails to detect an iterating variable when evaluating a generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Consider the following code:

```
print([a for a in [0] if eval("a in [0]")])
b = 0
print([b if eval("True in (x == b for x in [0])") else ''])
print([a for a in [0] if eval("True in (x == a for x in [0])")])
```

The output of this is:

```
[0]
[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "…", line 4, in <module>
    print([a for a in [0] if eval("False in (x == a for x in [0])")])
  File "…", line 4, in <listcomp>
    print([a for a in [0] if eval("False in (x == a for x in [0])")])
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <genexpr>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

The first eval uses the iterator `a` in a plain eval, and it works.

The second eval uses a static variable `b` when evaluating a generator, and it works.

The third eval combines the two ideas - it uses an iterator variable when evaluating a generator, and it fails to detect the variable and raises an error. Why does this happen?

Comment: This works in Python so your tag should be Python 3.x instead.

Comment: And in Python 3, if you supply the `locals()` dict for the list comp, it works: `[a for a in [0] if eval("True in (x == a for x in [0])", locals())]`. Though I still can't wrap my head around why this works for others and fails here.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: That's treating `locals()` as the global scope for the `eval`uated code, so variable lookup inside the genexp's nested scope looks there instead of skipping it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A genexp, like `(x == a for x in [0])`, creates its own scope.
- So do list comprehensions, at least in Python 3.
- Nested scopes inside an `eval` don't see variables from the locals used for the `eval`.

That means that in this line:

```
print([a for a in [0] if eval("True in (x == a for x in [0])")])
```

The `a` lookup inside the `eval` happens in a nested scope, so it doesn't see the `a` variable from the local variables of the scope where the `eval` occurred.

Comment: "Nested scopes inside an eval don't see variables from the locals used for the eval" Is this documented somewhere? I can't glean that fact from the docs.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I'm not seeing it in the `eval` docs, but it's kind of documented for [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec): "If exec gets two separate objects as globals and locals, the code will be executed as if it were embedded in a class definition."